# How to remove the extra white space at the bottom of the panels

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down menu system. My drop down panels contains a list menu and 3 images.

```css
#menu {width:1000px;margin:0px auto 0px auto}
#menu #holder{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 list-style:none;margin:0px;padding:0px;
}
#menu .menuaholder{margin:0;padding:0;display:inline-block;width:auto}
#menu .menudropdown{z-index: 3;position:absolute;display:none;background-color:#ffffff;-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #c4c4c4;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #c4c4c4;
box-shadow: 0 0 6px #c4c4c4;}
#menu .menuaholder .full{padding:10px;width:980px;text-align:left;}
#menu .menuitem{display:block;padding:5px;color:#000000;}
#menu .menuitem:hover{background-color:#edf0f1;color:#B7B67E;}
#menu .menuaholder:hover .menudropdown{display:table;}
#menu a.item{
list-style-type: none;
list-style-image: none;
color: #999999;
padding: 5px 6px 6px 6px;
height: 15px;
font-size: 12px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
text-transform: uppercase;
 }
.menudropdown .fourblocks .block{width:25%;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;float:left}
.menudropdown .fourblocks .block:last-child{margin-right:0px}
.menudropdown .fourblocks{display:inline-block;margin-bottom:0px;width:980px}
.twoblocks img, .fourblocks img, .menudropdown .fourblocks img, .threeblocks img, .unevenblocks img, .unevenblocks2 img{display:block;width:100%;height:auto;}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
<div id="holder">
<div class="menuaholder even"><a href="index.html" class="item">Lighting</a><div class="menudropdown full">
<div class="fourblocks">
<div class="block">
<a href="wall-lights.html" class="menuitem" title="Wall Lights">Wall Lights</a>
<a href="spot-lights.html" class="menuitem" title="Spot Lights">Spot Lights</a>
<a href="pendant-lights.html" class="menuitem" title="Pendant Lights">Pendant Lights</a>
<a href="chandeliers.html" class="menuitem">Chandeliers</a>
</div>
<div class="block">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="LINK" title="LINK" width="200" height="200"></div>
<div class="block">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="LINK" title="LINK" width="200" height="200"></div>
<div class="block forie">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="LINK" title="LINK" width="200" height="200"></div>
</div>
</div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/s7yr93hj/ to show you.

The panels have 10px padding around the contents, however at the bottom of the panels, I seem to have a gap larger than 10px, which I would like to remove.

My first thought was that the images were `display:inline`, but my styling includes `display:block` to remove any unwanted white space beneath them, however the problem still exists.

The outer div seems to have a height greater than the contents. The drop down panels will have varying heights, so I do not want to add `height` to the styling drop down panels

Does anyone have a solution to remove the extra white space?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser also renders white space on `inline` elements, the quick fix would be set the container `font-size:0` and reset it to `font-size:16px` on the items.

But in your case you could just remove `.menudropdown .fourblocks {display:inline-block;}` all together, and set it to `float:left` if you want.

**Updated Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/s7yr93hj/1/

Answer (score 0):

Change `inline-block` to `inline` on the `.fourblocks` div